# Crystal Reports Formula to generate a random number

Tags: crystal-reports, report, logic, formula

Let assume

x = 1001
Now I am inputting x to my code and generating y in the following order:

```
Length of 1001 is 4 so starting from the last number
```

i.e. 1(number) * 4(position of number) & 0 * 3 & 0 * 2 & 1 * 1 that gives a new number 4001

Another eg. 1234 gives 16941

In crystal I am creating a formual as follows:

```
stringvar tmp_EventNo;
stringvar tmp_Password;
numbervar i;
numbervar m_password;

    tmp_EventNo = Trim(ToText({GR_EVENT.event_number}));
    For i := Len(tmp_EventNo) To 1 Step -1 Do 
        (
        tmp_PassWord = tmp_PassWord & Trim(ToText(Val(Mid(tmp_EventNo, i, 1)) + i));
        );                   
    m_Password = Val(tmp_PassWord);

m_password
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Just results in 0.00

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice easy one- you will kick yourself :)

In Crystal `=` is used for evaluation. `:=` is used for assignment.]

There were a few other issues with the code so i tweaked it for you:

```
stringvar tmp_EventNo;
stringvar tmp_Password;
numbervar i;
numbervar m_password;

    tmp_EventNo := Trim(ToText({GR_EVENT.event_number}, 0, ''));
    For i := Len(tmp_EventNo) To 1 Step -1 Do 
        (
        tmp_PassWord := tmp_PassWord & Trim(ToText(Val(Mid(tmp_EventNo, i, 1)) * i,0));
        );                   
    m_Password := Val(tmp_PassWord);

tmp_PassWord;
```

Comment: You are a Legend! Damn man.. Sometimes code gets soo much in your mind that you overlook small things such as this.

Comment: Hey, good answer. you might consider editing the question -- improving the formatting and wording, for example -- to make it more helpful to other people trying to solve similar problems.